# How to speed up clone of a Git Repo into Docker Container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-packaging

I have some code from an external Python repository that I use in a Dockerfile.

```
RUN git clone ssh://git@foobar.com/sample_repo.git /sample_repo
```

How can I get all of this code to be (A) accessible in the Docker container; (B) way faster than `git clone`; (C) pick up recent code changes in the repository?

Before I go down the path of creating a [private Python package repository](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/project-management/how-to-create-a-private-python-package-repository/), I want to be sure I implement a solution that plays well with Docker and factors in all of the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want recent code changes to be fetched into an existing container, there isn't really a way around running `git clone` in the container, so that you can later `git pull`.

If you don't need the entire history, then perhaps [git clone --depth 1](https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones) would speed up the initial clone.

```
RUN git clone --depth 1 ssh://git@foobar.com/sample_repo.git /sample_repo
```

> By providing an argument of --depth 1 to the clone command, the process
>   will copy only the latest revision of everything in the repository.
>   This can be a lifesaver for Git servers that might otherwise be
>   overwhelmed by CI/CD (Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery) automation.

If you don't want `git` at all in the container, and are comfortable rebuilding the image to get code changes, then a helper script that does a `git archive` to the host machine, and then an `ADD` statement in the `Dockerfile` would work too.